# Getting null values calling method in initState() in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

```
   // I called widget from widget
   Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/placebids', arguments: {
  'ProductId': productDocumentId,
  'ProductName': productName,

});


String productId, productName ;

  @override
 void initState() {
   super.initState();
   _fetchBidofAllTheUsersForCompare();
  }

 Future<void> _fetchBidofAllTheUsersForCompare() async {
 final QuerySnapshot _dbr = 
    await Firestore.instance.collection("Pro-$productName-$productId").getDocuments();
    List<DocumentSnapshot> templist;
  templist = _dbr.documents;
  List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>> list = new List();
  list = templist.map((DocumentSnapshot ds) {
      return ds.data;
  }).toList();
    list.forEach((item) => {
      item.forEach((key, value) => {
        print(value)

  })
});
```

}

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final routeArguments =
    ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as Map<String, String>;
productId = routeArguments['ProductId'];
productName = routeArguments['ProductName'];
return Scaffold();
}
```

Getting the null values of ProductId and ProductName when i try to call the method in initState();If those values i am receiving in Widget then how to use it in initState method

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar null value problem, the null value problem when I used `DocumentSnapshot`

```
final DocumentSnapshot_dbr = 
    await Firestore.instance.collection("Pro-$productName-$productId").getDocuments();
```

only `documentsnapshot_dbr`

Comment: plus be careful to use  'await' whenever you use firestore operations in case of future operations