# Flutter initState does not run the method called

Tags: flutter, dart, listview

I am sure I am missing something quite obvious but, just not able to understand why is this happening.

I call a method called readJSON which reads a JSON file into an object. I use the length to render the pages and each page has a list of checkboxes based on the index of main object.

I have used: https://github.com/afzalali15/onboarding_demo to build this Onboarding task within my app.

*Just to note, while I was implementing this, I saw the hot reload work perfectly fine. When I closed VSCode and opened it again later, readJSON method never runs.

```
class _OnboardingPageState extends State<OnboardingPage> {
  List<OnboardingTodo> onboardingTasks = [];
  final _controller = OnboardingController();
  String response = '';

  bool value = false;

  Future<void> readJson() async {
    response = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/cfg/onboarding_tasks.json');
    final onboardingTodo = onboardingTodoFromJson(response);
    onboardingTasks.addAll(onboardingTodo.values);
    print("onboarding length - " + onboardingTasks.length.toString());
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    readJson();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            PageView.builder(
              controller: _controller.pageController,
              onPageChanged: _controller.selectedPageIndex,
              itemCount: onboardingTasks.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Container(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Image.asset(
                        _controller.onboardingPages[index].imageAsset,
                        height: 100,
                        width: 100,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 32),
                      Text(
                        _controller.onboardingPages[index].title,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 32),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Container(
                          child: ListView.builder(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                            itemCount: onboardingTasks[index].tasks.length,
                            itemBuilder:
                                (BuildContext context, int chkBoxindex) {
                              return CheckboxListTile(
                                controlAffinity:
                                    ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
                                value: value,
                                title: Text(
                                    '${onboardingTasks[index].tasks[chkBoxindex].title}'),
                                onChanged: (bool newVal) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    value = newVal;
                                  });
                                },
                              );
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
            // The dots showing the index of the pages
            ...
            // The next/end button
            ...
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Any help, or suggestions is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I checked the following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60082129/getting-null-values-calling-method-in-initstate-in-flutter but I could not get an answer

Comment: how you get null if `readJson` return nothing, please, show error

Comment: Sorry, I changed the title a bit. So the method does not execute. So anything I use based off that is a null.

Comment: Should you use "await" in the function call? await readJson();

Comment: it's return error

Comment: You can try `void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance
        .addPostFrameCallback((_) => readJson(););
  }` or ProgressLoader

Comment: check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
void initState() {     
  super.initState();     
  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => readJson(););   
}
```

or Use Loader like

```
bool loading = true;
  Future<void> readJson() async {
    setState(() => loading = true);
    response = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/cfg/onboarding_tasks.json');
    final onboardingTodo = onboardingTodoFromJson(response);
    onboardingTasks.addAll(onboardingTodo.values);
    print("onboarding length - " + onboardingTasks.length.toString());
    setState(() => loading = false);
  }
```

and put loader into UI like

```
itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return loading ? YourProgressIndicatorWidget : Container(child: ......
}
```

Comment: This is so close, it stopped crashing now after I added the Progress Indicator like you suggested. However, the screen goes blank now. Need to hit Save on VSCode and everything refreshes and the data is on.

Comment: Just saw this error: flutter: No observables detected in the build method of Observer

Comment: don't quite understand, try to change `bool loading = false;` to `bool loading = true;` and add `setState` to `readJson()` for `loading = ... `

Comment: can you share more about error?

Comment: Thank you for this... It is magic literally. It worked after I added setState to loading=

Comment: yes, I forgot to mention this. happy coding)

Comment: All that is left now... is to understand how to add shared pref to remember the state of the checkboxes

Comment: use SharedPreferences or GetStorage, check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/69222948/13859627

Comment: Oh the link is helpful, realised best practice is to use shared pref. I hardly have data to warrant a DB. Is it possible to used Shared_Pref even in my case? isDone var is in an object. onChanged: `(bool newVal) { setState(() { onboardingTasks[index].tasks[chkBoxindex].isDone = newVal; });},`

Comment: Yes, you can, if you want save data on device.
If you have difficulties in using, create a new question, you will definitely be helped with this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237318/discussion-between-vivian-lobo-and-novol).